# How do I enable weapon hits/killing players in a custom room in Rec Room?

Tags: rec-room

I am unable to kill or get killed in my custom rooms. Shooting people does nothing. How do I change that?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Arqade SE. If you haven't already read [the Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and have a look [to the help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance. I don't play this game, but it looks like your problem happens in a special mode where you define rules. You might want to give more details about this, like which rules you are using, so other users can hopefully help you.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ways to set up eliminations in a game:

- You can use the Game Rules Chip to automatically manage respawns, eliminations, and health for you with some limitations on flexibility.
- You can manage health and eliminations via the Player Hit chip that gives you flexibility on how players receive damage and how they respawn.

For your usecase, you may be able to get by with just the Game Rules Chip. There are many options to sort through, which you can read more about [here](https://rec-room.fandom.com/wiki/Game_Rules_Chip), but ultimately you only need 3 components to enable hits and eliminations in your room: a game starting system, a configuration for weapon damage, and a way to respawn players and revive them.

### Starting the Game

Hits are only registered when the game is running, so either make it so that the game automatically starts when there is the correct number of players in the room with the "Automatic Game Start" setting, or spawn in a scoreboard from the props menu that players can use to start the game manually.

### Configuring Weapon Damage

You'll want to ensure that the "Suppress Weapon Damage" toggle is unchecked. This option is only for if you want to manage health in your own circuits. Then, you can configure how much health each player has with the "Max Health" and "Max Shield" settings.

### Respawning

You'll need to setup a few respawn pads for your players. If this is a team based game, you use the configure tool on the respawn pad to set which team respawns at which respawn pad. Be sure to put these in safe locations to prevent spawn killers from ruining the fun.

If you want the game rules chip to automatically respawn players after they are eliminated, make sure the "Auto Respawn Supported" option is selected. You can then configure how long it takes someone to respawn with the "Auto Respawn Delay". Make sure you also check the "Restore Health on Respawn" button as well, otherwise your players will stay eliminated after respawning.